# Configure XAMPP with MySQL4

Tags: mysql, configuration, xampp

Can we configure MySQL 4 with XAMPP? The latest version of XAMPP comes with MySQL5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. You can disable MySQL from XAMPP control panel and separately install MySQL4 and configure it as a service.